# PHP: Буква ф пропадает при приведении к нижнему регистру

Tags: php, html, кодировка

У меня есть код, обработчик запросов с VK.com. Код для чатбота. Когда я преобразую исходную строку (В UTF-8) в нижний регистр, использую функцию mb_strtolower($str, “UTF-8”)

Но на выходе из этой функции буква ф превращается в непонятный символ, а все остальные буквы преобразуются нормально. Как решить такую проблему?

Comment: Наверное, потому, что ф у вас в другой кодировке..?

Comment: Строка на входе подаётся в одной кодировке, а потом, как я выяснил, в ходе некоторых преобразований (я удаляю все символы кроме букв и цифр из строки) буква ф (только она одна) преобразуется неверно и отображается как (?)